# Condição IF / ELSE em expression no Jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports, condição

Preciso realizar uma verificação no campo `expression` em meu relatório criado no `Jasperreports studio`, minha situação é a seguinte, preciso realizar a seguinte conta:

```
$F{quantidade}/($F{quinze}/15.0)
```

Porém algumas vezes a conta `($F{quinze}/15.0)` resulta em zero, e não é possível realizar uma divisão por zero, por esse motivo acaba sendo exibido em meu relatório o simbolo do infinito, minha necessidade é verificar se a conta `($F{quinze}/15.0)` resultar em `0` quero alterar o retorno para que seja apenas `$F{quantidade}` e não o resultado da conta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas olhando a [documentação](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/using-java-language-expressions), fiz essa formula utilizando [operação ternária](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_tern%C3%A1rio), vê se atende ao seu problema:

```
(($F{quinze}/15.0 == 0) ? $F{quantidade} : ($F{quantidade}/($F{quinze}/15.0)))
```

Answer (score -2):

$F{quinze} == 0 ? $F{quantidade} : $F{quantidade}/($F{quinze}/15.0)

ainda é possível adicionar outras condições no "if" com os operadores || (or) e && (and)

só não esqueça de circundar a condição com parênteses caso haja mais de uma, ou apresentará problemas. sendo apenas uma condição não há problemas em deixar fora do parêntese, inclusive acho que fica visualmente menos poluído